# Query objects where the pointer object matches any objects within a PFObject array

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

My class Posts has a column that is a pointer to another class called Styles. Each post must be associated to a Style object as a rule of thumb.

**My problem: I can't get only the posts that are associated to one or more styles.**

My object `selectedStyles`, that is an array of PFObjects that already contains the style objects I would like to use to match the query. So populating the `selectedStyles` is not an issue, but how to use it to produce my query is.

What I am doing at the moment is:

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {

    var query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
    query.whereKey("bellongsToStyle", containsAllObjectsInArray: [selectedStyles])
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    return query
```

If I could translate the whereKey method in plain english I would say:

`...contains - ANY OF THE - PFObjectsInArray [selectedStyles]`

I am not so sure if that is possible... any ideas?!

Comment: what is the problem that you are getting or ... what are you trying to accomplish

Comment: my question's second paragraph **I would like to only get the posts that are associated to one or more styles.** but my problems is how to achieve that using a PFObject array as a key in my query

Comment: Use the findobjectsinbackground

Comment: how would you implement that for a queryForTable()  on a PFQueryTableViewController? any examples?!

Answer (score 2):

I think I am too late for this but you can just add

> **[IncludeKey:"bellongsToStyle"]**

when you are querying in your 'Posts' class
don't need to run any extra query for that

here's a small reference
http://blog.parse.com/announcements/queries-for-relational-data/